# Edit the default VS 2010 Silverlight Project Template

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, project-template

Does anyone know where I can find the default Silverlight Project Template used in Visual Studio 2010. Every time I create a new SL project I need to add one namespace in MainPage.xaml, so I thought it would be nice to add it straight into the template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the example here:

[Changing the default class template in Visual Studio 2010](http://blog.hitechmagic.com/?p=437)

They are all basically zipped up files, but you must refresh the cache afterwards for them to be visible.